# Getting "Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception" despite having an @ExceptionHandler

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am getting some log messages such as these:

```
2023-09-18 09:45:56.270 ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is XXXXX]
```

The problem is not the exception - I know what caused it (a remote service was unavailable), and the exception is expected.

The issue is that a have an `@ExceptionHandler` to handle those exceptions. Furthermore, the handler is being used - I get log messages produced by that handler. But despite that, some of the exceptions are either not handled by the `@ExceptionHandler` and end up in this very general error handling (which basically logs them), or end up additionally in this `dispatcherSerlvet` error handler. I haven't been able figure out which is the case.

Does anyone have an idea why the exceptions are ending up in the `dispatcherSerlvet` error handler, despite having a working `@ExceptionHandler`? Or how these logs can be supressed?

Comment: I found out that this log is generated by the `org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve` class.

Comment: I have this same error, but I really don't know what is causing my exception...